# res.redirect is not work inside passport function

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

In my login module after enter all the details , I am using passport.js, if the details are correct it will return user value.

In my route.js

```
app.post('/verifyotp', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-otplogin', function (err, user, info) {
            if (err)
            {                        
            return next(err); }
            if (user) {
                console.log("user is there")
                req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                    console.log("req.logIn")
                    if (err) { 
                        console.log("err")
                        return next(err); 
                    }
                    console.log("No err") //Printing this value
                    console.log(req.user)

                    mongo.user.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': user._id }, { 'log_count': 0 }, { upsert: true }, function (err, response) {
                    });
                    return res.redirect('/dashboard'); // but redirect is not happening

                });
            }
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

am getting req.user value too but redirecting to dashboard is not happening.

Is any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed in the console ?

You sure you don't enter in the case in which there's no err, but user is not defined ?

```
passport.authenticate('local-otplogin', function (err, user, info) {

   if(err)
   {
     console.log("An error occured");
   }
   else if(user)
   {
      console.log("user authenticated");
   }
   else
   {
      console.log("No error but user not found");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fixed my issue

Comment: Hello @Vishnu, could you share how did you fixed your issue?